# Strange behavior in subsetting R data frame

Tags: r

Here is the test:

```
x = data.frame(a=1:10, b=2:11)
x$b[2:5] = NA
x[x$b<9, ]
```

Result:

```
      a  b
1     1  2
NA   NA NA
NA.1 NA NA
NA.2 NA NA
NA.3 NA NA
6     6  7
7     7  8
```

First, why on the earth does it include those NA entries in `x$b`?
And even if this makes sense, why then does change all corresponding
entries in `x$a` into NA?

I hope I am not making a stupid mistake somewhere.
I am using R 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Documented in the "NAs in indexing" section of `?"["`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at what `x$b<9` evaluates to

```
 [1]  TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE
 [7]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It has `NA` values in there. When you use a logical vector for indexing, TRUE means you should include the row FALSE means you should exclude the row, but what NA means is unclear, so what R does is just return a row of NA values because you haven't really asked to include or exclude a row so you get a weird mix of possible values.

A common way around this is

```
x[which(x$b<9), ]
```

which automatically drops the NA values because they are not TRUE

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the test, `x$b<9`.  Comparing a value against NA returns NA, which is not what you want:

```
x$b<9
## [1]  TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Try this instead:

```
x[!is.na(x$b) & x$b<9, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact behavior you should expect. `NA` is a logical value which basically means that no comparison can be made.  So when you make the comparison `NA < 9` the answer is that no comparison could be made.  `NA` isn't a number so how do you compare a non-number to a number?  So when you pass that logical vector into your `data.frame` to subset it when it gets to a point where there is an `NA` it does basically the same thing.  It says "this is neither supposed to be here nor not be here (i.e. not `TRUE` or `FALSE`) it's somehting different, it's `NA`" so it returns `NA` for those places.  You can avoid this like this:

```
x[which(x$b<9), ]
```

Where `which()` simply returns the indices of `TRUE`.